# Android ADB shell. Is it possible to use the 'input text' command to enter a random character?

Tags: android, shell, input, command, adb

Thank you in advance for any help here.

I am currently testing an application and I need to find a way to enter a random text string into ADB using the

```
adb shell input text <string>
```

Instead of entering only what is typed into the `<string>` field.

Is this possible? Iv'e been trying to come up with a creative way to do this with no luck.

Thank you for any help.

Update:

I may have figured it out using the `%RANDOM%` msdos code. This uses only numbers although. I will leave this here if anyone else runs into this issue.

Comment: If you're doing this in a Windows batch script, you could try the techniques at https://superuser.com/questions/349474/how-do-you-make-a-letter-password-generator-in-batch or https://stackoverflow.com/a/25046053/423105 to generate random text.